# Which pattern to use for case when necessary to recovery state of application?

Tags: typescript, oop, design-patterns

I have some observer methods that return data from server. This result is applied to filters (HTML form with data inputs). These filters are related each others. It means when I choose one filter it loads another.

Brief illustration is:

```
Load data from server -> 
Assign response to variable and assign to filter -> 
Choose value from filter -> 
Fill others filters -> 
Load content on the page based selected filter
```

User can leave this page and return after.

How to provide user statement of page with selected filters and content avoiding repedly server request?

Comment: You can try to save a memento of that object periodically, probably on his local storage, and rebuild those filters later using the memento before registering your listeners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your component shall accept kind of `@Input` object that is able to re-create state. You should update this object and store it in service-like class to persist it's lifetime across pages in-out movement. Concept you are trying to solve is similar to ones that `ngrx store` is addressing.

Storing mechanism is not hard, what sould be in this object is hard. If you don't want to rely on cached data, then stream you described (i.e. filters dependency) shall be stores in order to re-initialize component with fresh data. If you are not concerned with some in-meanwhile updates of data, than storing data (and filter values for view consistency) is needed, but no API-calls will be done. All the magic shall be push into onInit` in my opinion.

### EDIT

As mentioned in comments, consider memento design pattern from GoF as a reference to your design